# generate a dictionary which shows the number of friends using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

If given an array of friends like `[[A,B],[A,C],[B,D],[B,C],[R,M], [S],[P], [K,L]]` need to write a function that creates a dictionary of how many friends each person has. People can have 0 to many friends. However, there won't be repeat relationships like `[A,B]` and `[B,A]`.

I have tried the following, but not sure if this is the right approach.

```
def friend_tree(ls):
    f=sum(ls,[])
    newdict={}
    for i in range(len(f)):
        if f.count(f[i]) > 1:
            newdict[f[i]]=f.count(f[i])
        elif f.count(f[i]) == 1:
            newdict[f[i]]=f.count(f[i])-1
    return newdict
```

Input:

```
friend_tree([['a','b'],['a','c'],['a','d'],['b','w'],['b','e'],['f'],['g']])
```

Output:

```
{'a': 3, 'b': 3, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'w': 0, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 0}
```

Comment: Did you run into any problems? If not, this is a right approach

Comment: in your sample, there is `['b','w']` so why you want ` 'w': 0`?

Comment: this is working fine, was not sure if this is the best approach or if I am doing something terribly wrong, or did not catch any use case that might pop up.

Comment: @alireza Seems like "friendship" is directed here. 

Comment: If friendship is directed, how does ['A', 'B'] and ['B', 'A'] count as "repeat relationships"? The two are different, no?

Comment: @TrebledJ exactly, it’s not clear that friendship is directed or not

Answer (score 0):

you can use `defaultdict` like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

m = [['a','b'],['a','c'],['a','d'],['b','w'],['b','e'],['f'],['g']]
res = defaultdict(int)
for rel in m:
    for p in rel:
        if len(rel) > 1:
            res[p]  += 1
        else:
            res[p] = 0
print(res)
```